# Add to TexStudio autocompletion

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

I'd love to know how to add the `eqnarray*` environment to autocompletion, I only get the regular `eqnarray`. (I'm using Windows 7)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. — Why do you use `eqnarry` anyway? See [eqnarray vs align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196).

Comment: Hahaha, I forgot about that! I'll start to use `align` then, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For completeness: You find more info on how the completer works in the [FAQ](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Frequently%20Asked%20Questions/#why-does-a-command-not-show-up-in-the-completion).

In the special case of `eqnarray*`, it's not really missing but included in `l2tabu.cwl`. This is not loaded by default, because `eqnarray*` is deprecated. If you insist to use it for some reason, you can include it by checking `l2tabu.cwl` at Options -> Configure -> Completion -> Use following completion files.

Answer (score 2):

Otherwise, if you want allow completion with personnal command, you need to create a CWL file in the personnal folder (C:\Users\XX\AppData\Roaming\TeXstudio\completion\user).

On each lign you write your commands, in this form :

```
\command
\commandWithText{text}
```

You can see arguments example here : http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION

Don't forget to activate you personnal CWL file in the TexStudio settings !

Answer (score 1):

Typing the first parts of the environment `\begin{eqn`, there should be a `\begin{eqnarray}` listed in the pop up for autocompletion. It should look like this. (I am using `version 2.6.2` by the way and it should work in any platform.)

[image]

But as suggested, you should use the `align` or `align*` environment instead. In order to activate text completion for `align` and other `amsmath` environments, click

> Options > Configure TeXstudio... > Completion

then click on the check box for `amsmath` as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but he wanted to use `eqnarray*`. ;) Either way, the canonical way for auto-completion for an environment is (after typing `eqn`) `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Space`.

Comment: Hi @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks for letting me know about the `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Space`. I just hit `Enter` after typing enough characters to isolate the specific text completion for the command/environment as I find it faster that way, or scroll down to the specific command/environment. Am I missing something by not using `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Space`?

Comment: Well, `Enter` works only because “Automatically start completer when typing LaTeX-Commands” in the “Completion” tab of the Configuration checked. Without it, you first need to do `Ctrl`+`Space` (the completion for macros). You’re missing typing `\begin`! ;) I learned about `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Space` due to [a bug concerning completing environment](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/566/) which is long fixed.

Comment: I see now. Perhaps I missed your earlier comments. I have to get back to this a little later though. Thanks!

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I am getting a bug when I hit `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Enter`. I get an extra `}` at the end of the environment. File in https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/775/

Comment: You don't type the `\begin` part. Simply type `enu`, then `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Enter` will create `\begin{enumrate}<cursor>\end{enumerate}`.